# Add Repeating Task With Redis

Tags: python, heroku, redis

**How do I schedule a task to run once every six hours (on repeat)?**

I am trying to implement a Redis queue for the first time.

I went through Heroku's tutorial : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq

But the tutorial did not explain how to run a task repeatedly with a timeframe (such as checking a couple of websites for info, once every six hours)

Also, since I am new to do this, if I should not be using Redis for such a task, please let me know what I should be using to check a couple of websites for info once every six hours

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Redis for this functionality at all.

Take a look at the Heroku Scheduler here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

You can set this to run your code every hour, and have your code check if the current hour is 0,5,11,17 (or whatever other interval you may need).